# R networkD3 package: edge coloring in simpleNetwork()

Tags: r, networkd3

Is there a way to colour the edges of the network using the package `networkD3` in R? All I have seen is ways of colouring the nodes but I have not seen anything regarding colouring the edges? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the help file with `?simpleNetwork`

it describes all the possible arguments, including...

> linkColour - character string specifying the colour you want the link lines to be. Multiple formats supported (e.g. hexadecimal).

```r
library(networkD3)

Source <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
Target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)

simpleNetwork(NetworkData, linkColour = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: one last question is it possible to specify the colour based on the value of a third variable? for example, red for those links with a negative value and green with those links with a positive value?

Comment: `simpleNetwork(NetworkData, linkColour = NetworkData$colour)`, assuming your data has a `colour` variable